# POST request with Json body to MVC resful service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, wcf, rest

Trying to construct valid request to wcf restful service. But whole hour cannot do it, i dont get it  why it's not work. Other APis what returns JSON works correctly, i tested them. Now need to fix request API. 
[image]

I put break point to implementation of AddMeal method but she don't triggered. I think something wrong with my request or with Attributes

```
    //Add Meal
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddMeal",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
    bool AddMeal(string meal);
```

Comment: What error do you get? Attach a debugger to find out, or open the "Application" event log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WCF method is expecting a `string`, however, the model binder will try to bind your JSON to a string which won't work. When using MVC you should use models instead, create a model that represents your JSON data e.g.

```
public class Meal
{
    public DateTime EatedTime { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public int PatientID { get; set; }
    public int MealTypeID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then update your signature to expect that model

```
bool AddMeal(Meal meal)
```

You should find the data is bound to the `meal` model.

Comment: Thanks! it's helps! I decide to use NotMapped property to conver string to DateTime  with my models. One else question, is needed to apply  [DataContract]  and [DataMember] to my models ? i see it work anyway

Comment: @Ark No the default model binder should handle the deserialization. However, as it's WCF you may need to do that if you are returning a model i.e. `Meal GetMeal(...)`.

Comment: i mean that i want to use the same model to interact with database via EF and use this models for WCF service: bindings, validation, etc

Comment: @Ark again, like I said only if you intend on *returning* that model from WCF. Those attributes are used by the `DataContractSerializer` and would be used to serialize the model to be sent across the wire.

Comment: Do you know how to determine MealType with null key and force WCF successfully bind it to my models

Comment: @Ark I am not sure what you mean?